# How to obtain smooth histogram after scaling image?

Tags: python, opencv, histogram

I am trying to linearly scale an image so the whole greyscale range is used. This is to improve the lighting of the shot. When plotting the histogram however I don't know how to get the scaled histogram so that its smoother so it's a curve as aspired to discrete bins. Any tips or points would be much appreciated.

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread(r'/Users/harold/Documents/Academia/Nottingham Uni/Year 4/ImageProcessing/Imaging_Task_Sheet/PointImage.jpeg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

img_s = img/255
img_s = img_s / np.max(img_s)
img_s = img_s*255

histogram = cv.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
histogram1 = cv.calcHist([img_s.astype('uint8')], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])

plt.figure()
plt.title("Grayscale Histogram")
plt.xlabel("grayscale value")
plt.ylabel("pixels")

plt.plot(histogram, label='Original Image')  # <- or here
plt.plot(histogram1, label='Equalised Image')  # <- or here
```

The histogram produced is:

[image]

Which is from this picture:

[image]

Comment: My guess is you are going for a nice bell curve? (in this case)

Comment: Why do you need to find the histogram in order to scale the image. You can use skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(image, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)). That will find your input range automatically and scale to the range 0,255 or whatever you want to specify.

Comment: Official docs have a nice python tutorial on [histogram equalization](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you have in mind is a spline curve that passes through your points. Here is how to do it:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy import interpolate

img = cv.imread(r'3NKTJ.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

img_s = img/255
img_s = img_s / np.max(img_s)
img_s = img_s*255

histogram = cv.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
histogram1 = cv.calcHist([img_s.astype('uint8')], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])

x=np.linspace(0,len(histogram1),len(histogram1)) # x: 0 --> 255 with step=1

X=np.where(histogram1>0)[0] # extract bins with non-zero histogram1 values
Y=histogram1[X] # the corresponding Y values

F=interpolate.splrep(X, Y)   # spline representation of (X,Y)
Ynew = interpolate.splev(x, F) # calculate interpolated Ynew

plt.figure()
plt.title("Grayscale Histogram")
plt.xlabel("grayscale value")
plt.ylabel("pixels")

plt.plot(histogram, label='Original Image')  # <- or here
plt.plot(histogram1, label='Equalised Image')  # <- or here
plt.plot(x,Ynew, label='spline interpolation of Equalised Image')
```

Below, the result:
[image]

Best regards,
Stéphane

Answer (score 3):

You should read about [gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction):

using the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701330/4734439) which uses an automatic way to calculate the gamma value, you get the following results:

Method1:

[image]

Method2:

[image]

And the corrected image's histogram (method 2) looks like this:

[image]

**Edit2: **
Or you could use a linear method to rescale each channel between 0 and 255. Using this code:

```
def apply_white_balance_single_channel(img, low_ratio=0.001, high_ratio=0.001):
    hist_size = 256
    hist = cv2.calcHist([img], [0], None, [hist_size], [0,hist_size])
    acc = np.cumsum(hist)
    low_limit = low_ratio * acc[-1] 
    high_limit = high_ratio * acc[-1]
    min_gray = 0
    while acc[min_gray] < low_limit and min_gray + 1 < hist_size: 
        min_gray += 1
    max_gray = hist_size - 1
    while acc[max_gray] >= acc[-1] - high_limit and max_gray > min_gray:
        max_gray -= 1
    input_range = max_gray - min_gray
    alpha = (hist_size - 1) / input_range
    beta = -min_gray * alpha
    return  (alpha * img + beta).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

def apply_white_balance_multi_channel(img, low_ratio=0.001, high_ratio=0.001):
    channels = cv2.split(img)
    return cv2.merge([apply_white_balance_single_channel(ch, low_ratio, high_ratio) for ch in channels])
```

Which gives the following result:

Rescaled Image:

[image]

The histogram:

[image]

**Edit3**

Or you could use a simpler version to do the linear rescaling using a simple min-max normalization:

```
def apply_white_balance_multi_channel_min_max(img):
    channels = cv2.split(img)
    return cv2.merge([cv2.normalize(img, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX) for ch in channels])
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is possible if you're linearly scaling the image. However, you could give OpenCV's [Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html#clahe-contrast-limited-adaptive-histogram-equalization) a try:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('3NKTJ.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_clahe = img.copy()
img_clahe = img_clahe/np.max(img_clahe)
img_clahe = (255*img_clahe).astype(np.uint8)

clahe = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=5, tileGridSize=(3,3))
img_clahe = clahe.apply(img_clahe)

img_s = img/255
img_s = img_s / np.max(img_s)
img_s = img_s*255

histogram = cv.calcHist([img], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
histogram1 = cv.calcHist([img_s.astype('uint8')], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])
histogram2 = cv.calcHist([img_clahe.astype('uint8')], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])

plt.figure(dpi=100)
plt.title("Grayscale Histogram")
plt.xlabel("grayscale value")
plt.ylabel("pixels")

plt.plot(histogram, label='Original Image')  # <- or here
plt.plot(histogram1, label='Equalised Image')  # <- or here
plt.plot(histogram2, label='CLAHE Image')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can play around with the `clipLimit` and `tileGridSize` to get the image look the way you want. The [default values](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#gad689d2607b7b3889453804f414ab1018) are `40.0` and `(8, 8)`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to linearly scale an image so the whole greyscale range is used

To increase the dynamic of the image, there is common image processing method called "Histogram equalization" (see: `cv.equalizeHist()`, [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/dc7/group__imgproc__hist.html#ga7e54091f0c937d49bf84152a16f76d6e))

To have a better result, you should remove extremes values of the image, to remove under/over exposuition.

To do so, on the equalized image:

- compute the cumulative sum of the histogram
- find the first intensity lower than `rate` and the first higher than `1-rate`
- trim all image intensities to those 2 values.

Here's a sample code:

```py
def equalize_hist(data: np.ndarray, rate: float) -> np.ndarray:
    data = cv.equalizeHist(data.astype(np.uint8))

    hist = np.cumsum(np.histogram(data, 255)[0])
    lowest_value = np.where((rate * hist[-1]) <= hist)[0][0]
    highest_value = np.where(((1 - rate) * hist[-1]) >= hist)[0][-1]

    sdata[self.data < lowest_value] = lowest_value
    data[self.data > highest_value] = highest_value

    return data
```

A common value for `rate` is 0.05. As you increase the rate, you increase the dynamic of the image, but lose information. You can't raise `rate` higher than 0.5.